# Sending a request through Angular to the SpringMVC controller,which inreturn renders a new View

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Is it possible that the request made from the angular  to the spring mvc controller , so that the new view can be rendered by the Spring Controller and not by the angular route mapping???

If any ,please help me out with some suggestions...

This is my angular requesting code.

```
 $scope.validateLogin=function(bLoginInfo){

    var User=$resource("http://localhost:8080/Customerinfo/billingLogin.html");
     User.save($scope.bLoginInfo,function(response){
         $scope.result=response.message;
         bLoginInfo.username="";
         bLoginInfo.password="";

         if(angular.equals($scope.result,"valid"))
             {
                 var bHome=$resource("http://localhost:8080/Customerinfo/BillingHome.html");
                 bHome.query();// Request to Spring Controller to render new view
             }
         })
        }
```

And this is the controller that should render the view.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/BillingHome")
   public ModelAndView redirectToMainHome(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws JSONException
   { 
        return new ModelAndView("Billing/BillingHome","hdata",hdata);

   }
```

with my current code , the request is just entering the Spring controller but the view is not rendered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have addObject method in ModelAndView class for add json data and it will return view,check here

```
@RequestMapping(value="/BillingHome")
public ModelAndView redirectToMainHome(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws JSONException

{ 
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Billing/BillingHome");
   modelAndView.addObject("hdata", "hdata"); 
   return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestion sir, but i got the solution using  "location,replace(// the request url in spring)"

Comment: its ok Nishi keep it up.